# http to https redirection not working while accessing admin area which pretected by htpassword

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have used below code to redirect from http to https & www to non www.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

And inside admin directory I have used below code to password protect admin directory.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/public_html/admin/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

While accessing the admin using https mode like below

```
https:://example.com/admin
```

Its working fine but while accessing with http mode instead of redirecting its redirecting to an error page

```
http:://example.com/admin
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer of my question from below StackOveflow question

[Do HTTP authentication over HTTPS with URL rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220167/do-http-authentication-over-https-with-url-rewriting?rq=1)

I was missing below 2 things.

```
 SSLRequireSSL
 ErrorDocument 403 https://www.example.com/secure-page.php
```

Thanks